# performSegue in Swift 3 app not working

Tags: ios, swift

I am using Parse Server deployed on Heroku and MongoDB for my Swift 3 IOS app. When i open my home view controller I want to check if there is a user alredy logged in and if there is not I want it to perform a segue to go back to the login page. The function correctly states that there is no user logged in and also hides the log out button. The segue does not work though. Here is the image of what is happening:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDI2l.png)

Comment: Your segue not working probably has nothing to do with the current user existing or not.  Nor Heroku, Parse server, or Mongo DB.  Is your segue correctly named in the storyboard?

Comment: Please edit your question to post your code and not just a picture of it.

Comment: @vacawama Thanks worked perfectly!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to perform the segue before the view has appeared. Move your call to an overload of `viewDidAppear`.